# CSS nth-child issue while setting display to none

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="section fp-section fp-table active"></div>
<div class="section fp-section fp-table"></div>
<div class="section fp-section fp-table"></div>
<div class="section fp-section fp-table"></div>
<div class="section fp-section fp-table"></div>
```

All five divs are exactly the same and just add 'active' pending on which div is selected. How would I go about removing the forth div? I've tried nth-child and displaying none, but had no luck.

Comment: you can use $('.section').eq(3).remove()

Comment: nth-child seems to work fine... look, no 4 http://www.cssdesk.com/gWq4k

Comment: sorry, I should have specified more. In this case, display none would work fine. thanks for replying!

Comment: you should also have shown what you tried so we could tell you what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
div:nth-of-type(4){
   display:none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJsdp)

Answer (score 2):

Jquery Version

```
$('div:nth-child(4)').remove();
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJsdp)

You can also hide() instead of remove() that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative way to achieve this:

```
div:nth-last-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope it also helps!

Answer (score 0):

nth-child worked fine for me

```
div:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hIyDm